# How do I access XAML bound class properties in code? (C#, WPF form)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

In the example below, I am using XAML to set the DataContext to a class name, not an object name (as far as I can tell). The binding works - the txtEcho textbox shows what is entered in the txtName textbox when the latter loses focus. I want to be able to access the properties of this class in code-behind so I need an object reference. I could create a Person object and set the DataContext to that  but the pattern in the books I am consulting does not do that - the class name is used and an object is not explicitly created in the examples in these textbooks.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:Person x:Key="personData" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource personData}" />
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,41,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtName" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="78,42,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtEcho" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="262,42,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code is

```
namespace WpfApplication5
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //txtFreedom.Text = <what exactly?>.Name; // no object reference!
        }
    }
    class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.name; }
            set
            {
                this.name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `DataContext` to get ViewModel instance. Though better would be (depends on what you are trying to do) to create `ICommand` in the ViewModel and bind button `Command` to it instead of using click event.

Comment: @Sinatr: could you provide an example using the app example above? The Grid.Datacontext object: how do I access it? I gave the Grid a name so I could check its properties and DataContext was not there. I will look into ICommand.

Comment: Interesting. I created a DataContext instance and set it to the Grid's DataContext. I checked it was a Person object. But it has no Name property! This confuses me.

Answer (score 2):

You could access the `Person` instance that you create in your XAML like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Person person = this.Resources["personData"] as Person;
    txtFreedom.Text = person.Name;
}
```

Comment: @Moonling: Did you try this or what happened?

Comment: Yes I tried it, mm8, and it worked. Surely there is a more-or-less standard way to access the viewModel's data in code? It must be an extremely common need. What is a recommended way to access the viewModel class instance from any method in the application? (I'm a beginner by the way)

Comment: I added this line   
        `public static Person oPerson;` at the top of the MainWindow class and `oPerson = this.Resources["personData"] as Person;` in the MainWindow() method so I could access the Person instance in other methods. I got the compilation error Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'WpfApplication5.Person' is less accessible than field WpfApplication5.MainWindow.oPerson'

Comment: Please don't ask additional questions in the comments section. Ask a new question if you have another issue. And please remember to accept the answer and vote it up if your original question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, with mm8's help. The code is now

```
namespace WpfApplication5
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static Person oPerson;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            oPerson = this.Resources["personData"] as Person;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtFreedom.Text = oPerson.Name;
        }
    }

    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.name; }
            set
            {
                this.name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The differences are, Declare a public static variable to hold a Person object.

```
public static Person oPerson;
```

In the MainWindow() method set it to the behind-the-scenes Person instance.

```
 oPerson = this.Resources["personData"] as Person;
```

I had to make the class public to stop a compiler accessibility objection.

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Now I can reference the properties of the instance.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         txtFreedom.Text = oPerson.Name;
    }
```